# Working of javascript inline functions

Tags: javascript

I am not able to grasp how `function(match, p1, p2)` is working.

What is use of match parameter? The code breaks if I don't write match parameter.

```
function incrementString(input) {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(input[input.length - 1]))) return input + '1';
    return input.replace(/(0*)([0-9]+$)/, function(match, p1, p2) {
        var up = parseInt(p2) + 1;
        return up.toString().length > p2.length ? p1.slice(0, -1) + up : p1 + up;
    });
}
```

P.S: I am new entirely using Js for development. However, I have been working on JSF and Java since past few years.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[, flags])
```

In that case, we can see that two arguments are passed to `replace`, a regular expression literal and a function expression. So that's:

```
str.replace(regexp, function)
```

and MDN tells us what they are:

> function (replacement)
> A function to be invoked to create the new
>   substring (to put in place of the substring received from parameter
>   1). The arguments supplied to this function are described in the "Specifying a function as a parameter" section below.

and

> The arguments to the function are as follows:

etc. etc. I won't quote the entire table.

If you leave the `match` argument out of the parameter list, then the values assigned to `p1` and `p2` will be the first and second argument instead of the second and third. Those won't be the values you need.

It would be like taking this code:

```
function call_with_one_two_three(f) {
    f(1,2,3);
}

call_with_one_two_three(function (one, two, three) {
    alert(two + three);
});
```

And deciding that since you weren't using `one` you didn't need it:

```
function call_with_one_two_three(f) {
    f(1,2,3);
}

call_with_one_two_three(function (two, three) {
    alert(two + three);
});
```

That giving you `two + three` as `3`.

In short: **The position of arguments matters** (and the name doesn't).